# Labeling polygons with geom_sf, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, dplyr, r-sf

I am attempting to label polygons from a spatial feature data frame using ggplot2. I am trying to replicate the description [here](https://ryanpeek.github.io/2017-11-05-mapping-with-sf-Part-2/) under the heading, "Download Some Boundary Data: State/County/HUC"

This is my code to try to get the lat and lon values to use for the label location in geom_text():

```
selected_sites <- arc.open(survey_sites)
ss <- arc.select(selected_sites)
ss_shape <- arc.data2sf(ss)
refcode_list <- ss$refcode

ss_shape <- ss_shape %>%
  mutate(lon=map(geometry, ~st_centroid(.x)[[1]]),
         lat=map(geometry, ~st_centroid(.x)[[2]]))
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
>         Evaluation error: `.x` is not a vector (closure).

Comment: Why not just simply save the centroids to a new `sf` object that you can pass to `geom_text()`? eg) `ss_centroids <- st_centroid(ss_shape)`. Lon will be X and Lat will be Y.

Comment: This works for me if I use sample data from the spdep package converted to an sf class polygons data frame, and use library(purrrr). Can you make a reproducible example? Also, this is really inefficient because you are calling `st_centroid` twice. Much quicker and direct to cbind the coordinates: `G = cbind(G, st_coordinates(st_centroid(G$geometry)))`

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce the error myself. It's possible you don't have the `purrr` package loaded and so `map` is picking up a different function.

I would say that since your goal is to plot labels in `geom_text`, simply using `st_centroid(ss_shape)` would be the way to go. It would return your centroids as `points` which you can pass directly to `geom_text`:

eg)

```
ss_centroids <- st_centroid(ss_shape)
ggplot()+ 
  geom_text(data=ss_centroids,aes(x=X,y=Y,label=name))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the poster's error, so unless you can I wouldn't jump to conclusions about what the problem is. WIthout library(purrr) I get "could not find function map". Not the poster's error....

Comment: @Spacedman yes, you would get that error if you had no packages loaded with the 'map' function. It's possible he has another `map` function which is producing the error but as you point out, it is a guess - so I have edited the comment to make clear. The second point I made is the most important part of the answer anyhow.